# gravity form notification customization

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, gravity

I have built a gravity form in wordpress. I have around 20 text fields. but when I submit the form then i see all 20 fields in the email. But I want to show only those fields in email which has values if there is no value in any field then it should not show up. 
Any idea how to achieve that functionality

Answer (score 1):

To send all submitted fields you can use the placeholder {all_fields} in the notification template to send out just those that get submitted.

{all_fields} is the same placeholder that gets uses when the default admin notification is created.